# Shiny as a diamond - What am I?

Tags: riddle

> Shiny as a diamond
>   Once thought to be under the sea
>   Better than a snake
>   I seek to bring joy to many
>
> You are my master, I control your slave
>   Read my words only where defined
>   If you don't exist, to me, you're a liar
>   Tell me what I am, if you'd be so kind.

*Every line has meaning, (Well, maybe not the last one, that's just a rhyme to finish the poem) so you have to explain it **all***

Comment: I'm guessing you're Perl, but this time I don't have an explanation for even half the lines.

Comment: People like to make riddles about programming languages here, I see.

Comment: Nah, just warspyking. He's already made three so far.

Comment: @JoeZ, What lines can't you explain? I can explain 1,2,3,5?,6,7

Comment: I can explain 1, 2, 3, but none of the others. I don't know enough about Perl to explain them. Perhaps you post the answer to this one.

Comment: Lines 4 and 5 could be said of about almost any programming language. Can't explain 7 though.

Comment: Number 7 is the tendency for many programming languages to treat nonexistence as "false" when checking for a boolean value. The same behaviour is exhibited by C, C++, Java, Javascript, Python with the `not` keyword...

Comment: @JoeZ. Of course.. should have thought of that!

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Comment: @warspyking Wasn't me who downvoted, but I think it's because you've overmined this category of riddle. You wrote a good riddle and it was upvoted, but then you wrote and posted two very similar ones within a day, seemingly with less care. These types of bandwagons never work out well, even if you're riffing off of yourself. And, the riddle is less fun to solve when people already know what type of answer to expect from metagaming you being the author.

Comment: @xnor But that doesn't change the quality of this riddle. I worked hard on all 3 of these, I shouldn't get DVed just because I posted them quickly, DV/UV is supposed to judge the *quality* of a question, not if you agree when the posters habits.

Answer (score 10):

Taking this in another direction, because the OP rejected my first answer,

Shiny as a diamond

> Rubies are shiny, as are diamonds.

Once thought to be under the sea

> the two proposed names for the language were Ruby and Coral.

Better than a snake

> Ruby advocates claim it is better than Python (citation needed)

I seek to bring joy to many

> Matsumoto, Ruby's creator wrote "For me the purpose of life is partly to have joy. Programmers often feel joy when they can concentrate on the creative side of programming, So Ruby is designed to make programmers happy."

You are my master, I control your slave

> Programmers control computers

Read my words only where defined

> A reference to undefined variables

If you don't exist, to me, you're a liar

> Undefined values evaluate as false in Ruby, as in many languages.

Tell me what I am, if you'd be so kind.

> The Ruby language

Comment: Read my words only where defined is incorrect, but Ruby is correct.

Comment: @warspyking [This?](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/) (Spoiler alert)

Comment: @ace No ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 5):

Shiny as a diamond

> Pe[a]rls are shiny, as are diamonds.

Once thought to be under the sea

> Double meaning: Some consider perl to be not as good as (and thus under) C; also, pearls come from the ocean

Better than a snake

> Perl is clearly better than Python (citation needed)

I seek to bring joy to many

> Language was written to fill a gap in available languages; also, see any of Larry Wall's early State of the Onion talks.

You are my master, I control your slave

> Programmers control computers

Read my words only where defined

> A reference to both perl's use as a text processing language and to undefined variables

If you don't exist, to me, you're a liar

> Undefined values evaluate as false in perl

Tell me what I am, if you'd be so kind.

> The Perl language

Comment: Yeah, I think the third line is pretty contentious too. Python all the way! :D

Comment: This is incorrect. Not just the explanations, the answer is not Perl. Nice try though.

Comment: If you take luster into play, the first line is wrong. Pearls have a pearly luster(obviously) and diamonds have an adamantine luster. These two shines are very different.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel has the correct answer, but it has not been accepted because one of the hints was not explained satisfactorily. I would like to offer an explanation in hope that his answer can be selected.

Read my words only where defined

> The contents of variables can only be read within the scope in which they were created

Comment: (This would probably have been better left as a *comment* on the relevant answer, than as an answer in its own right.)